# $X$ is connected iff there is no continuous surjection $X \rightarrow\{0,1\}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

Let $X$ be a metric space. Prove the equivalence of the following:

> [image]

Please confirm if my attempt is fine or contains mistakes! Thank you so much!

**My attempt:**

(a) implies (b): Assume the contrary that $f:X \to \{0,1\}$ is a continuous surjection and $A = f^{-1}(0), B = f^{-1}(1)$. Then $A,B$ because $\{0\},\{1\}$ are open in $\mathbb R$ and $f$ is continuous. Moreover, $A \cap B = \emptyset, A \cup B = X$. Because $f$ is surjective, $A,B\neq \emptyset$. As such, $X$ is not connected, which is a contradiction.

(b) implies (a): Assume the contrary that $X$ is not connected. Then there are two nonempty open disjoint subsets $A,B$ such that $A \cap B = \emptyset, A \cup B = X$. We define $f:X \to \{0,1\}$ by $f(x)=0$ if $x\in A$ and 1 otherwise. It is easy to verify that $f$ is a continuous surjection, which is a contradiction.

Comment: $\{0\},\{1\}$ are not open in $\mathbb{R}$, but in the induced topology on $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting my misunderstanding @MichaelBurr!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Then $A,B$" is not a sentence. You mean "Then $A,B$ are both open". Then the argument is correct, but don't say that $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are not open in $\Bbb R$ but say they open in the induced *subspace topology*.

For the reverse actually show, instead of "claim", that $f$ is continuous. There is a helpful glueing lemma that might help. With that little gap filled, it's correct.

Comment: Yeap tha't what I meant ^^

Comment: Is this correct in my following approach? There are only 4 open subsets of $\{0,1\}$ wich is $\{0\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\}, \emptyset$. We have $f^{-1}(0) = A, f^{-1}(1) = B, f^{-1}(\{0,1\}) = X, f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$. As such, the pre-image of every open sets are open.

Comment: @Akira Yes, that would be correct and from the definitions. "wich is" should become "which are", of course, and "every open set" instead of "every open sets".

Comment: Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @Akira You're welcome. And "are open" should be "is open". "Every x" gets third person singular endings.

Comment: How passion you are in help ;))))